# What's wrong with my version of this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

This is the steps to find the correct answer:[[image]][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5VUv.png)

I used trig identities instead and got a different answer. I checked it multiple times, and I'm not sure what I did wrong: [image]

Comment: be careful $\frac{d}{dx}cos(x)^4 \neq  -4sin(x)^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int -\sin^3 x dx \ne \frac{\cos^4 x}{4} + C$